# Как обработать массив через foreach?

Tags: php

Всем доброго дня.

Задача такая - по ключу, найти максимальное значение массива и удалить из массива все элементы, ключ которых меньше максимального.

Массив имеет такой вид

```
Array
(
 [response] => Array
    (
        [count] => 41
        [items] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 12345
                        [from_id] => 12345
                        [date] => 1480622801
                        [text] => Text
                        [likes] => Array
                            (
                                [count] => 0
                            )

                    )
                ...
```

Я нашла способ, как найти максимальное значение массива -

```
foreach($members['response']['items'] as $k => $val){
$array_ataj[] = $val['likes']['count'];
}

echo max($array_ataj);
```

Но как при этом, оставить массив с максимальным значением (то есть, чтобы мне вернули ключи и значения) не знаю.. Прошу помощь в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$max = null;
foreach($members['response']['items'] as $k => $val){
  $cnt = $val['likes']['count'];
  if (!isset($max) || ($max < $cnt))
    $max = $cnt;
}

// Перенумеровываем ключи
$members['response']['items'] = array_merge($members['response']['items']);
for ($i = count($members['response']['items']) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  if ($members['response']['items'][$i]['likes']['count'] < $max)
    unset($members['response']['items'][$i])
}
// Перенумеровываем ключи
$members['response']['items'] = array_merge($members['response']['items']);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вроде все работает.

Answer (score 1):

ну я конечно не очень понял сути вопроса
и комменты ставить не могу, но:

```
$max = 0;
$id = array();
foreach($members['response']['items'] as $k=>$v){
    if($v['likes']['count'] > $max){
        $max = $v['likes']['count'];//Сначала нужно установить максимум
    }
}
foreach($members['response']['items'] as $k=>$v){
    if($v === $max){
        $id[] = $k; //Затем находим все элементы кол-во лайков у которых соответствует максимуму
    }
}
$random_array = $members['response']['items'][array_rand($id)];//так получится случайная запись
foreach($id as $k=>$v){//а так можно работать с каждой
    $entry_id = $id[$k]; //номер записи из $members
    $likes = $members['response']['items'][$entry_id][likes][count]; //количество лайков
    $entry_array = $members['response']['items'][$entry_id]; //сам массив из $members
}
```

Comment: Простите за корявое описание. Вроде как почти то, только как вместо $id получить массив этой записи

Comment: @Eva_m исправил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое... И последний нюанс. Что будет, если будет 2 максимальных значения?

Comment: @Eva_m будет отображено последнее. Я оставил так, поскольку не было указаний если будет больше одного. Перефразирую ответ

Comment: а можно, чтобы выводил не последнее, а случайное?

Comment: Исправил ответ, если нужно случайное, то вместо `foreach...` пишем 

`$random_array = $members['response']['items'][array_rand($id)]`

Comment: То есть вместо `foreach($max as $k=>$v){
    $likes = $v; //количество лайков
    $entry_id = $id[$k]; //номер записи из $members
    $entry_array = $members['response']['items'][$entry_id]; //сам массив из $members
}` пишем `$random_array = $members['response']['items'][array_rand($id)];`

Comment: @Eva_m исправил ответ еще раз

Comment: @Eva_m ну и последний ваш коммент тоже верен, да, я чет видать недочитал там, или изза того что форматирование сбилось не понял

Comment: Спасибо, невероятно помогли. Последний, глупый вопрос. Как результат на экране получить. var_dump($entry_array); Возвращает NULL

Comment: Смотря в каком виде получить. Странно, по сути должно работать
но если просто вар_дампом, то все верно, вы правильно написали. НО, если вы заменили `foreach...` на `$random_array = ...`, то и выводить нужно `var_dump($random_array);`, мб поэтому? о:

Comment: В виде, как вы сделали 1 раз. var_dump($random_array) - тоже null

Comment: Я правильно поняла. В данном варианте, мы получаем максимальное значение. И, если этих максимальных значение 2 и более - выводим случайное из них?

Comment: да, правильно, ошибку нашёл
исправлю ответ

Comment: Исправил, вроде как должно корректно работать. Сорри за затупость на старте, без чата тяжело конечно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49480/discussion-between-sly-huh-and-eva-m).